# CSS: How to remove left&right border of a row in the table?

Tags: html, css

1) I need to make a table with one row having NO border like this (this table has one 3 rows, but actually in my problem, it has a lot of rows)

```
+---------+---------+               +---------+---------+ 
|         |         |               |         |         |
+---------+---------+               +---------+---------+
|         |         |      --> 
+---------+---------+               +---------+---------+
|         |         |               |         |         |
+---------+---------+               +---------+---------+
```

How can I do this?

2) I need to create another table with different width of the row. But here I set `width: 350px;`for `td`. So for the new table, how should I change the row width ?

```css
.frame {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin-right: 80px;
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 11pt;
}

table, th, td{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-left:80px;
}

td {
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 350px;
    height: 20px;
    padding-left: 6px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

th {
    width: 350px;
    padding-left: 6px;
}
```

```html
<div class ='frame'>
    <table style ='margin-top:20px; font-weight: bold'>
        <tr>
            <td>(0,1)</td>
            <td>(0,2)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>(1,0)</td>
            <td>(1,1)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>(3,0)</td>
            <td>(3,1)</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Remove `border` from your `table` and have that on your `td`s instead. Then just do a `tr:nth-child(2) td { border-left: none; border-right: none; }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this, where you remove the border on the `table` and, in this case, set it on the `td`s, and then remove it from the second `tr`'s `td`s

```css
.frame {
    margin-right: 80px;
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 11pt;
    margin-left:80px;
}

.tbl-special {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin-top:20px;
    font-weight: bold
}

.tbl-special td {
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 350px;
    height: 20px;
    padding-left: 6px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    border: 1px solid black;        /* moved from "table, tr, td" rule */
}

.tbl-special th {
    width: 350px;
    padding-left: 6px;
}

.tbl-special tr:nth-child(2) td {
    border: none;                   /* remove all borders on second row */
}
```

```html
<div class ='frame'>
    <table class='tbl-special'>
        <tr>
            <td>(0,1)</td>
            <td>(0,2)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>(1,0)</td>
            <td>(1,1)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>(3,0)</td>
            <td>(3,1)</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

---

You could also use below rule, though in this case it does not matter, since you used `border-collapse: collapse;` on the `table`

```
.tbl-special tr:nth-child(2) td {
    border-width: 1px 0;            /* remove left/right border on second row */
}
```

Comment: thanks for your solution. But if I do this method, ALL the tables will be affected. Besides, i have some other tables in my page, not only one.

Comment: @htmlamateur Updated my answer

Comment: How can I use this trick for only this table, and how can I change the row width for another tables because here I set `width:350px` for `td` already, right now it has also affect to all the tables.

Comment: thanks a lot, but all the others tables belong to `.frame` also :(

Comment: @htmlamateur Updated again... added a class to this particular table

Comment: thanks a lot LGSon! accepted your solution. Have a nice day! :)

Comment: @htmlamateur Thanks...and for you too